# Proving the properties of subspace (coset)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ over a field $F$.
Let $v\in V$. We define
$$v+W=\{{v+w:\ w\in W\}}$$

Show that

> i) $v+W$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $v\in W$
>
> ii) $v_1+W=v_2+W$ if and only if $v_1-v_2\in W$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Is there a certain part of the problem that is giving you difficulty?

Comment: I have problem on manipulating the W in equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

i) : $0$ is in any subspace. So if $v + W$ is a subspace, what vector is in $W$ to get $0$?

(ii): Supposing the equality, we get that $v_1$ is in $v_2 + W$, so what vector is in $W$?